# How can play a SWF File on Page Load Then Redirect to "Default.aspx" in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, flash, redirect

I want to play a SWF clip on page load and after that automatically, redirect to another page ("Default.aspx"). Thanks a lot...

Comment: I think that your question will be closed because it's too board. You have to write (try) something and if you still have problems, post them here ...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the duration of the swf you can add a meta tag in head like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20; url=http://example.com/Default.aspx" />
```

Where "20" represents the amount in seconds and the URL to the destination address